# HtmlTable loses its HtmlRows while iterating and adding them to a HtmlTable in markup

Tags: c#, webforms

I created two HtmlTable(s) in my code-behind whereby each have their own respective HtmlTableRow(s). After I create these, I need to add them to a `<table name="teamoptionstable">` element in my markup in a specific order. But while I'm looping to add each HtmlTableRow to my teamoptionstable, the HtmlTable seems to delete the rows as I'm iterating. Here is the code:

```
HtmlTable gaTable = new HtmlTable();
HtmlTable supportTable = new HtmlTable();

HtmlTableRow gaHeaderRow = new HtmlTableRow();
gaHeaderRow.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell {
    InnerHtml = "<tr id='gaHeaderLeft'><th colspan='3'>G&A</th></tr>"
});
gaTable.Rows.Add(gaHeaderRow);

HtmlTableRow supportHeaderRow = new HtmlTableRow();
supportHeaderRow.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell {
    InnerHtml = "<tr id='supportHeaderLeft'><th colspan='3'>Support</th></tr>"
});
supportTable.Rows.Add(supportHeaderRow);

using(DataTable departmentList = Database.ObjectList_Get(Database.ObjectType.Department)) {
    foreach(DataRow department in departmentList.Rows) {
        int departmentId = Convert.ToInt32(department["department_id"]);
        string departmentName = department["name"].ToString();
        HtmlTableRow data = new HtmlTableRow();
        if (...) {
            data.Cells.Add(...);
            data.Cells.Add(...);
            data.Cells.Add(...);
            gaTable.Rows.Add(data);
        } else if (...) {
            data.Cells.Add(...);
            data.Cells.Add(...);
            data.Cells.Add(...);
            supportTable.Rows.Add(data);
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < gaTable.Rows.Count; i++) {
    teamoptionstable.Rows.Add(gaTable.Rows[i]);
}
for (int i = 0; i < supportTable.Rows.Count; i++) {
    teamoptionstable.Rows.Add(supportTable.Rows[i]);
}
```

The problem is at the end in my for loop. As it iterates the first time, for some reason, the gaTable.Rows.Count changes, it reduces by one. So I end up adding less rows to teamoptionstable. Here is the markup for the teamoptionstable:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped" id="teamoptionstable" name="teamoptionstable" runat="server">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Team</th>
            <th>Primary Rule</th>
            <th>Secondary Rule</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `HtmlTableRow` is a reference type. So when you add the reference to the row to another table, you are therefore removing the reference from the first table. This is similar to pointers in other languages.

Because of this, when you loop from 0 and up, you are only going through half of your rows.

Example. Here is your row collection:

```
Table 1: [0][1][2][3][4][5]
```

You take index 0 and add it to your new table. You are now left with this, since you took a reference from your first table. Notice how it shifts. You don't have indexes 1-5, you have indexes 0-4.

```
Table 1: [0][1][2][3][4]
Table 2: [0]
```

Then your loop increases more and you eventually reach this point:

```
Table 1: [0][1][2]
Table 2: [0][1][2]
```

Now when you get to index 3, there are no more. If you don't care about order, one thing you could do instead is iterate downwards, starting at the row count and working towards 0.

```
for (int i = gaTable.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    teamoptionstable.Rows.Add(gaTable.Rows[i]);
}
```

This will allow you to take from the end of the first table and account for the shift in indexes. This will obviously leave you with a reversed table, however.

If you do care about order, you'll need to recreate all the rows and cells new, then add them to your second table. [Here is a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3100089/3711928) by Daniel Dyson with a method to do just that. I made some modifications to it. This is untested, so be aware of that.

```
protected HtmlTable CopyTable(HtmlTable copyFromTable)
{
    if (copyFromTable != null && copyFromTable.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        var copyToTable = new HtmlTable();
        HtmlTableRow copyRow;
        HtmlTableCell copyCell;

        for (int i = 0; i < copyFromTable.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            copyRow = new HtmlTableRow();
            for (int j = 0; j < copyFromTable.Rows[i].Cells.Count - 1; j++)
            {
                copyCell = new HtmlTableCell();
                copyCell.InnerHtml = copyFromTable.Rows[i].Cells[j].InnerHtml;
                copyRow.Cells.Add(copyCell);
            }
            copyToTable.Rows.Add(copyRow);
        }

        return copyToTable;
    }

    return null;
}
```